# Android: How to retrieve data from MySQL and assign it to variable

Tags: php, android, mysql

As title, I would like to know how can i retrieve single variable from MySQL database and assign to variable.

```
   try{
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.25/userdatabase/include/GetSource.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        BasicResponseHandler handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String data = handler.handleResponse(response);
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);
        String path= jObj.getString("sources");

          }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Log_tag", "Error converting result" + e.toString());
    }
            mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
            mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(getActivity()));
            mVideoView.setVideoChroma(MediaPlayer.VIDEOCHROMA_RGB565);
            mVideoView.requestFocus();

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    // optional need Vitamio 4.0
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);

                }
            });
```

This is what I have try to retrieve the path from MySQL. But Failed to retrieve. 
Please Help

---

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
mysql_select_db("streaming");

$sql=mysql_query("select * from iptv where id = 1");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
json_encode($output);
print(json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
mysql_close();
?>
```

---

```
[{"sources":"http://210.200.79.25:1935/live/ttv.sdp/chunklist.m3u8"}]
```

Comment: You also need to post web service code .

Comment: **Failed to retrieve** does not clear the things. Can you please post the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: Also enter output of php code so we can understand where is wrong and also enter error you getting

Comment: I didn't get error. basically my full program is running a live steaming program, the path is RTMP video source, I knew it was failed to retrieve because the video cannot be play means it does not receive the source from MySQL ?

Comment: [{"sources":"http://210.200.79.25:1935/live/ttv.sdp/chunklist.m3u8"}] this is the JSON

Comment: Did you check, what are you getting in `data` in the android application?

Comment: Sorry, I'm noob at android, can you show me how do I check it.

Comment: Just type `System.out.println("Data received: "+data);` after you receive some data in `String data`. You can see the output in the logcat of your IDE.

Comment: Hi, i updated my program and it can show what am i exactly to do.
I cant use the path outside the try {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code. This should be your exact `try... catch` block. You will be able to access the `path` variable outside `try` block now.

```
String path = null;
try{
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.25/userdatabase/include/GetSource.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        BasicResponseHandler handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String data = handler.handleResponse(response).replace('"','\'');  //edited this line
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(data); //added this line
        JSONObject jObj = ja.getJSONObject(0); //edited this line
        path= jObj.getString("sources");

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Log_tag", "Error converting result" + e.toString());
}
```

It returned me the path that you are expecting.

Comment: App crash... Hmm I tried declare the variable like path = "http://hls.novotelecom.ru/streaming/fashion/tvrec/playlist.m3u8"; 
then the app run perfectly, once retrieve from MySQL. then app crash

Comment: I can't see the log cat since i using physical device, and android studio can't detect my device

Comment: I tried to make a project to list view the path. It work, and display the path correctly from MySQL, but if I make the path like mVideoView.setVideoPath(path); App Crashed

Comment: You need to get the logcat to see what the problem is. Try running the project on an emulator in Android Studio if you are not able to connect your phone. Also, the using `setVideoURI` instead of `setVideoPath`. You will need to convert your `path` to an URI like this: `Uri myUri = Uri.parse(path);`. Now pass this `myUri` in setVideoURI function.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not quiete a real answer but I am not allowed to comment yet.

You do not have a "data" field in your JSON response if I am not mistaken so calling it in your Android code will fail. So change this

```
String data = handler.handleResponse(response);
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);
JSONObject j_user = jObj.getJSONObject("data");  // why do you do this?
String path = j_user.getString("sources");
```

to

```
String data = handler.handleResponse(response);
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);
String path = jObj.getString("sources");
```

Also it seems strange to me that your JSON response is starting and ending with [ ] brackets. Maybe you have to convert this to a JSON array first and get the first JSON object out of it?
All of this should have caused an error in your Android code (the catch clause should be called) but you are saying that you do not get an error so I am not really sure whether my thoughts could help you.

**EDIT**:

You have to put the declaration of path outside the try and catch or all the code inside it. Also try to parse your response first to a JSON array. Try this one:

```
try{
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.25/userdatabase/include/GetSource.php");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    BasicResponseHandler handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String data = handler.handleResponse(response);
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(data);
    JSONObject jObj = array.getJSONObject(0);
    String path= jObj.getString("sources");

    mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(getActivity()));
    mVideoView.setVideoChroma(MediaPlayer.VIDEOCHROMA_RGB565);
    mVideoView.requestFocus();

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            // optional need Vitamio 4.0
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
        }
    });
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Log_tag", "Error converting result" + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you correction. I updated my code please give me advise. why is  mVideoView.setVideoPath(path); not able to execute

Comment: Did you check out the edit ? What value does path have after getting it from the JSONObject ?

Comment: I think my problem is because the value that I retrieve is a URL. When I display my path in listview .. It does show the content as http://hls.novotelecom.ru/streaming/fashion/tvrec/playlist.m3u8... but when I assign it as variable like mVideoView.setVideoPath(path); .. It doesn't work